# Como utilizar o "define_method" corretamente no Ruby?

Tags: ruby, dinâmico

Eu estava pesquisando na internet a como criar métodos dinamicamente em *Ruby* e em alguns fóruns em inglês, as pessoas falavam para utilizar o método `define_method`, passando um nome para o método e um *&block* que seria o corpo deste método. Eu tentei fazer isso porém ele não cria o método para mim.

**Veja o código abaixo:**

```
class Cachorro

    define_method :falar do
        puts "Au au!"
    end

    def method_missing(method_name,*args)

        if method_name == :andar
            define_method :andar do
                puts "Andando..."
            end
        end

    end
end

animal = Cachorro.new
animal.falar
animal.andar
```

Neste código, o método `falar` é criado, porém o método `andar` não. Porque isso ocorre ? Qual a maneira certa de se utilizar o método `define_method` ?

E aproveitando que estou falando sobre criação de métodos dinamicamente em Ruby, há alguma forma de se criar atributos dinamicamente desse jeito: `animal.nome = 'Bidu'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método `define_method` que você usou para criar o método `:falar` é um método de classe. O método `animal.falar` que você chama é um método de instância (o objeto `animal` é uma instância da classe `Cachorro`).

Para que a criação do método `:andar` funcione corretamente, você precisar executar o método da classe. Para isso, basta você alterar `define_method` para `Cachorro.define_method` ou `self.class.define_method`, assim o método será criado corretamente.

Porém, ele não será executado logo após a sua criação, você precisaria executar o método `:andar` duas vezes, uma para criar e outra com o método já existindo. Segue um exemplo de código onde o método será criado e executado logo em seguida:

```rb
class Cachorro

  define_method :falar do
    puts "Au au!"
  end

  def method_missing(method_name,*args)
    if method_name == :andar
      self.class.define_method :andar do # self.class
        puts "Andando..."
      end
      self.andar # executa logo após a criação
    end

  end
end

animal = Cachorro.new
animal.falar
animal.andar
```

---

Para atributos dinamicamente você pode usar o `instance_eval`. Por exemplo, nós podemos criar o atributo `nome` dinamicamente com o código abaixo:

```rb
class Cachorro

  define_method :falar do
    puts "Au au!"
  end

  def method_missing(method_name,*args)
    if method_name == :andar
      self.class.define_method :andar do # self.class
        puts "Andando..."
      end
      self.andar # define e executa
    else
      self.class.instance_eval do
        attr_accessor method_name
      end
    end
  end
end

animal = Cachorro.new
animal.falar
animal.andar
animal.nome
animal.nome = 'buddy'
puts animal.nome
```

Comment: Finalmente alguém me respondeu kkk. Obrigado, ajudou muito!